# No module named 'catkin_pkg' when installing ROS 2 Iron in a conda environment for MacOS

Tags: ros2, installation, documentation, macos

I'm trying to install ROS 2 Iron into a new conda environment on my Mac (ARM architecture). I was following the instructions in [this documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Installation/Alternatives/macOS-Development-Setup.html) but when I run `colcon build --symlink-install --packages-skip-by-dep python_qt_binding` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jkelle/ros2_iron/src/ament/ament_cmake/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/package_xml_2_cmake.py", line 22, in <module>
    from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package_string
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'catkin_pkg'

...

ERROR:colcon.colcon_notification.desktop_notification.terminal_notifier:Could not find the colcon-terminal-notifier.app in the install prefix '/Users/jkelle/miniconda3/envs/spl_ros'
```

I can see that `catkin_pkg` is installed an importable in my conda environment:

```
>> conda list | grep catkin_pkg
catkin_pkg                1.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
>> python -c "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package_string; print('success')"
success
```

I didn't disable SIP because I found [this discussion](https://github.com/ros-visualization/python_qt_binding/issues/103) suggesting it might not be necessary, and I really don't want to disable it if I don't need to.

My questions now are:

1. Is there a working conda installation option?
2. Do I really need to disable SIP?
3. How should I proceed?

Comment: I have same issue on fresh installation of macOS Sonoma 14.2.1 on M1 core and SIP disabled.

Comment: I try to build colcon from source, but no success. I am still getting error "Could not find the colcon-terminal-notifier.app." However I have checked the content of folder colcon-from-source/install/colcon-notification/ and the colcon-terminal-notifier.app is present in subfolder share/colcon-notification/.

Answer (score 0):

After some examination on macOS Sonoma I have managed to run `colcon build --symlink-install --packages-skip-by-dep python_qt_binding`. I am not completely done with build, but I made good progress. Below I summarize "hot fixes" I did. It is not clean approach, but it will enable to move on.

Prerequisities:

- you work in python virtual environment (venv)
- all ven prerequisites from Humble build tutorial are in place

Resolution of issue:

1. build colcon from source as described on [colcon install page](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/user/installation.html)
2. Check how is EXACT name of `colcon terminal notifier` filename in: `/YOUR_PATH/colcon-from-source/install/colcon-notification/share/colcon_notification`
3. Look for file: `'YOUR_PATH/colcon-from-source/install/colcon-notification/lib/python3.11/site-packages/colcon_notification/desktop_notification/terminal_notifier.py'`
4. Fix file name in function `def _get_app_path(prefix_path):`. In my case the name was: `colcon-terminal-notifier` *instead of* `colcon_terminal_notifier`
5. Additional issue occurs with python interpreter reference. I was unable to manipulate python target via colcon switch and environment settings. I just updated the makefiles directly, i.e.:

   ```
   ament_package_xml.cmake:
   ...
   set(_cmd
       #"${_python_interpreter}"
       "/YOUR_PATH/colcon-venv/bin/python"
       "${ament_cmake_core_DIR}/core/package_xml_2_cmake.py"
       "${PACKAGE_XML_DIRECTORY}/package.xml"
       "${dest_dir}/package.cmake"
   )
   ```